# How to make button 1 onClick to enable disabled button 2 in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 levels of buttons and level 2 buttons are disabled while some button on level 1 is clicked, and level 2 option is conditional, it depends on level 1.

However when button from level 1 is clicked I am not sure how can I enable the buttons on level 2 which depend on the button clicked on level 1.

I tried something like `getElementById` function but that doesn't work(it does change button style like it is enabled, but still is not clickable and won't even enable those on level 3). Also tried `setAttribute`, but I probably need something like state or ref which confuses me in this case, since I just started learning React and JS.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'


class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.someFunction=this.someFunction.bind(this);
    }
   
    someFunction(e){
        e.stopPropagation()
        var element= document.getElementById(Number.parseInt(e.target.id)+1)
        console.log("Clicked by " + e.target.id) // even if clicking 2 after change this won't print Clicked by 2
       element.disabled=0 //if not null

    }

    render() {
    return <div className="example">

        <button id="1" onClick={this.someFunction}>Level 1</button> {/* this is just example i have, db list of variations and logic*/}
        <button disabled={true} onClick={this.someFunction} id="2">Level 2</button>
        <button disabled={true} onClick={this.someFunction} id="3">Level 3</button>
    </div>


    }


}
export default Example
```

Here is an example of what I think.

In the scheme below I draw what I want to achieve. Basically buttons in level 1 don't have parents, those in level 2 have some parent from level 1 and so on until the last on which I will generate something.
The links between level 1 and level 2 depict which buttons should be enabled in level 2 if that button is clicked in level 1.

This is not important as the real problem is that for some reason in React I can enable the buttons in level 2 which have the link but they are becoming 'unclickable'.

[Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbsCQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use state so each element, or button, can render disabled or enabled based on the state values. If we have a `level` state value, each button can respect that value, as well as modify that value.

Here's a simple version of your buttons with the level state:

```js
const Example = () => {
  const [level, setLevel] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="example">
      <button level={1} onClick={() => setLevel(1)} disabled={level !== 0}>
        Level 1
      </button>
      <button level={2} onClick={() => setLevel(2)} disabled={level !== 1}>
        Level 2
      </button>
      <button level={3} onClick={() => setLevel(3)} disabled={level !== 2}>
        Level 3
      </button>
      <div>Level: {level}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I added a div at the end just so you can tell what the level is at any given point. Oh and you'll need to import `useState` from react:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a state that is called `isDisabled` and set up the logic of it according to the other level of buttons. On the button itself, you'll use that state for the logic:

```
 <button disabled={this.state.isDisabled} onClick={this.someFunction} id="n">Level n</button>
```